# Passing parameters to Javascript - works with 2, breaks with 3

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm working on an Add To Cart button, which passes an item's ID and Quantity to a Javascript function. The function processes the values, creates a temporary form to POST the values and then reloads the product page with ?AddItem added to the url.

This is the working code:

```
   function submitItem( ID, Code)
{
    alert("Submission received"); //--This is being triggered
    var toCart, inputA, inputB, quantity;

    quantity = Code.value;

    // Create form
    toCart = document.createElement( 'form' );
    toCart.action = " &AddItem";
    toCart.method = 'post';

    //Rest of the code excutes as normal
}
```

My product page is dynamically loaded, so the url for a category would  be blah.com/products.php?cat=FOO, but the AddItem removes the cat= clause, so a blank page is loaded. To circumvent this, I've tried passing the category prefix (FOO) to the javascript, but the addition of a third parameter is breaking it.

This is my new code:

```
function submitItemCat( ID, Code, Category )
{
    alert("Submission received"); //--This is not being triggered
    var toCart, inputA, inputB, quantity;

    quantity = Code.value;

    // Create form
    toCart = document.createElement( 'form' );
    toCart.action = " &AddItem"+ Category; //--This is were I amend the URL
    toCart.method = 'post';

    //Rest of the code
}
```

and the function call in html

```
$jsCat = json_encode($_GET["cat"]); // This is FOO

echo'
<div id= "QuantBox">
    <label for="Quantity">'.$catPrefix.'</label>
    <input type = "text"  name= "Quantity" id= "Q'.$row["StockCode"].'" value="1">
    <a 
        class= "AddToCart" 
        onclick= "submitItemCat( '.$row["StockID"].', Q'.$row["StockCode"].', '.$jsCat.' )" >
    </a>
</div>';
```

I've also tried passing the third variable as "FOO", $_GET["cat"] but none of them are working.
Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Do you get any JS errors in console? What is `Q` in the parameter list for your `onclick`? Does that not need quoting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably missing quotes.

A quick fix would be

```
    onclick= "submitItemCat( \"'.$row["StockID"].'\", \"Q'.$row["StockCode"].'\", \"'.$jsCat.'\" )" >
```

but this is horrible. Personally I'd refactor the code in order to avoid the building of inline javascript from PHP, for example by generating a clean javascript script with variable declared as

```
<script>
  var theid = '<?php echo $row["StockID"] ?>';
  ...
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I've managed to get it working by including the missing quotes. I tried refactoring it but I couldn't see any way to do it that would allow me to generate a unique set of vars for each item on the page.